# Open txt file grab the number count +1 and save it again

Tags: php, ajax

I have a text file `number.txt` and inside it there is only the number `1`.
I'm using the code below to open the file, get the number, add 1, update the content (must be 2) and save it again. My code is not working. Any suggestions?

```
$fp = fopen('number.txt', 'c+');
flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
$count = (int)fread($fp, filesize('number.txt'));
ftruncate($fp, 0);
fseek($fp, 0);
fwrite($fp, $count + 1);
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Where does it stop working?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

```
<?php
   $handle = fopen("test.txt", "r+");
   if ($handle) {
   $buffer = fgets($handle, 10);
   $nCount = (int)$buffer;
   rewind($handle );
   fputs($handle, $nCount+1);
   fclose($handle);
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with just

```
$path = 'number.txt';
file_put_contents($path, 1+(int)file_get_contents($path));
```